# padding zero to a column in CSV unix/Linux file

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, scripting

I need to update a column in CSV linux/unix data file. the CSV file have around 7 columns, need to update the 6th column and to make it have  4 digit values.
The 6th column is having digit's less that 4 digit but i need to make all values having 4 digit by padding 0 in front of them.

Is there is any awk or sed command that can update the column value to 4 digit in a file?

```
510;1093424;0;4485;C;12;109-04-115
510;109324;0;4485;C;1232;109-04-1151
510;109342;0;4485;C;1;109-04-1151
510;10424;0;4485;C;12;109-04-115
```

suppose the sample file is above, I need the 6th column to be 4 digit with zero added in front of it like this :

```
510;1093424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115
510;109324;0;4485;C;1232;109-04-1151
510;109342;0;4485;C;0001;109-04-1151
510;10424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115
```

Any suggestion will be helpfull

regards 
HG

Comment: Suggestion: before someone closes the question for lack of information and effort, post some sample input and expected output and what you have tried so far. And no, we do NOT want to see a file with 100 columns - make it something concise.

Answer (score 5):

In `awk` you can use `sprintf` to add zero padding:

```
awk -F';' -v OFS=';' '{$6 = sprintf("%04d", $6); print}' input.csv > output.csv
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/DdSPhB)

Comment: `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`. Wouldn't it be nice if back in the 1970s they had used IFS for input like they did with shell, and then FS could have meant "input and output" to save having to specify 2 different variables for  the common case that you want the same field separator for input and output? Oh well...

Comment: hi Barmer, I tried but that is not working it is add zero' in the last for eg

Comment: Can you add a few sample lines to the question?

Comment: 510;1093424;0;4485;C;12;109-04-115

510;109324;0;4485;C;1232;109-04-1151

510;109342;0;4485;C;1;109-04-1151

510;10424;0;4485;C;12;109-04-115


suppose the sample file is above, I need the 6th column to be 4 digit with zero added in front of it like this :

510;1093424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115

510;109324;0;4485;C;1232;109-04-1151

510;109342;0;4485;C;0001;109-04-1151

510;10424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115
 
 Any suggestions ??

Comment: Put it in the question so that line breaks are preserved.

Comment: That file uses semicolon as the separator, not comma.

Comment: Awesome. Worked like Breeez .Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[^;]+/\n0000&\n/6;s/\n.*(.{4})\n/\1/' file
```

Insert 4 `0`'s infront of field 6. Then reduce that field to length 4 from the righthand side.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't an elegant code, but gives the result you expect. AWK

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"}{ len=length($6); to_edit=$6; s=""; for(i=len;i<4;i++){ s=s "0"; } print $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS s to_edit FS $7; }

$ awk -f padding.awk padding.txt
510;1093424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115
510;109324;0;4485;C;1232;109-04-1151
510;109342;0;4485;C;0001;109-04-1151
510;10424;0;4485;C;0012;109-04-115
```